# How can i get a specific column value from multiple databases in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have more than 100 databases having a common table with a common column.
I need that column value from all the databases. Is there a way to get them all with a single query?
I'm using **SSMS** and all the databases using single user.

Comment: In a single query? Are all the db on the same server? Or if different servers, is one of the databases [linked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) to all the others ?

Comment: have you tried [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61638789)? theres also [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30287473). not sure what you have tried

Comment: Yes i have a master database and it contains a column db_name and having all databases names in it.@CaiusJard
I tried EXEC sp_MSforeachdb but this is giving me multiple results set one result for one database. but i need all values in one result set.

Comment: And you have a user that can access every db? You can query like `SELECT column FROM dbName1.schemaName.tableName UNION ALL SELECT column FROM dbName2.schemaName.tableName...`? - Bagus linked you to a W that advises how to build the query using dynamic even so you don't have to list out the db names by hand

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Query Across different database - Same table SQL Server 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30287439/query-across-different-database-same-table-sql-server-2012)

Comment: You can use temp table with `sp_MSforeachdb`

Comment: hey my issue was resolved 
this was helpful [Query Across different database - Same table SQL Server 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30287439/query-across-different-database-same-table-sql-server-2012)